# Rails renaming the routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to rename the routing of my email inputs for my rails app. Currently, when someone inputs their email, it routes them to /:controller/:id
I want to do it such that once they input their email, it won't show their id so they cannot change the id number and see other people's emails.

Comment: "when someone inputs their email" -> input where? Why don't you simply add `before_filter` to restrict that.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

i was trying my self and this dosn't works if its an email, but if you try it with a username with no special carracters it will work fine !

try something like this:

routes:

```
match "/controller/:username" => "controller#show"
```

controller:

```
def show
  @user = find_by_username(params[:username])
end
```

Comment: I tried it, but when they input their email, they are routed to /emailinputs/:id

Answer (score 0):

I think, use a permalink with some alphanumeric give secure email from another. for Assumes you have people model.

You only need to add one attribute to `people`, attribute name is `permalink`

try run

```
rails g migration add_permalink_to_peoples permalink:string
rake db:migrate
```

On `people.rb` , play with `before_save`

```
class People < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :permalink
  before_save :make_it_permalink

 def make_it_permalink
   # this can create permalink with random 8 digit alphanumeric
  self.permalink = SecureRandom.base64(8)
 end

end
```

And your `routes.rb`

```
match "/people/:permalink" => 'peoples#show', :as => "show_people"
```

on `peoples_controller.rb`

```
def show
  @people = People.find_by_permalink(params[:permalink])
end
```

Run `rails server` and add one people.

People have a unique permalink with random 8 digit alphanumeric (e.g `/people/:permalink`)

example : `http://localhost:3000/people/9sd98asj`